# How to use ComponentMeasurements with a matrix?

Tags: matrix, image-processing, image

The function `MorphologicalComponents` works on both images and matrices, as in the following code:

```
list = {{2, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {5, 6, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 5, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 8, 9}};
mc = MorphologicalComponents[list];
MatrixForm[list]
MatrixForm[mc]
```

[image: Image of the output from the above code]

I would have hoped `ComponentMeasurements` could be used similarly. For example:

```
ComponentMeasurements[list, "Mean"]
```

Unfortunately this does not work. For my requirements I found instead I can simply use:

```
ComponentMeasurements[Image[list], "Mean"]
```

This provides the desired result:

[image: Output from the above code, showing the mean calculated correctly]

However it feels like a bit of a hack, and I'm worried about it not working consistently, and for other measurements. Is there a better way to calculate the mean of these regions separated by zeroes. More generally is there a function similar to `ComponentMeasurements` that works with matrices?

Comment: This seems like a bug. According to the documentation, `ComponentMeasurements` should accept an integer label matrix as input. It just doesn't work reliably. You can use `ComponentMeasurements[{Image[list], mc}, "Mean"]`, if you don't trust it to work consistently with just an image argument.

Comment: Oh ok. Actually my main concern was that in some instances the function Image[list] might change the values of list, perhaps if they are too large or too small. Perhaps not. I'm not familiar with Image[]

Comment: @NikiEstner It'as not a bug.  `"Mean"` makes no sense for a label matrix, only for an image.  However, we can provide both an image *and* a label matrix, as `{image, labelMat}`.

Comment: @Tom Are you sure you are not confusing a *label matrix* with a *matrix of intensity values* (i.e. basically an image)?  They are conceptually different things.  For a label matrix, wrapping by `Image` is not a hack, it's plainly wrong. For the latter, it's also not a hack, it's the normal way to work with such data.

Comment: Yes, my `list` is indeed a *matrix of intensity values*. I find it odd that I have to convert to an image for the function `ComponentMeasurements `, whereas I can leave it as a matrix for `MorphologicalComponents`. Perhaps I'm making a fuss out of nothing ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is important to be aware of the distinction between matrices of intensity values (i.e. representing images) and matrices of label values (i.e. representing components).

If you have a matrix of intensity values, wrap it with `Image`.  This is what signals to `ComponentMeasurements` to treat it as an image, and not as labels.  You may want to specify [the underlying pixel type](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageType.html).  Note that Bit, Byte and Bit16 clip below and above the minimum and maximum values, while Real32 and Real do not clip the data (they simply *display* everything above 1 as white and everything below 0 as black, but they do preserve these out-of-range values intact).  `Image` will not modify the data you pass to it, except for potential clipping when one of the integral pixel types is specified (Bit, Byte, Bit16).

A label matrix is a matrix of integer values where entries (pixels) having the same value are considered to belong to the same component. A label matrix is often used in conjunction with an image.  It indicates which pixel of that image are part of the same component.  The most general syntax for `ComponentMeasurements` is

```
ComponentMeasurements[{image, labelMatrix}, ...]
```

If you only provide an image, the label matrix is automatically computed (`MorphologicalComponents`).

Some quantities, such as `"Count"` depend only on the label matrix and not the image. In this case, it is allowed to provide only a label matrix.

Some other quantities, such as `"Mean"`, require intensity values.  In this case, it is necessary to provide the image too.

---

To summarize:

`ComponentMeasurements` won't work with a plain matrix of intensity values because it decides what the input represents (intensities or labels) based on its datatype (i.e. [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html)).

- If the input is an [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html), it is always treated as intensities.
- If the input is a matrix ([`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html), [`MatrixQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixQ.html)), then it is always treated as labels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Although I am not confusing label matrices with a matrix of intensity values. I just don't understand why the process of calculating the mean of connected regions can't be done on a matrix itself, without wrapping it in an image. For example `MorphologicalComponents` can find the connected regions of a matrix, without one needing to wrap it as an image.

Comment: @Tom Because the function uses the head to distinguish between intensity values and label values.  Head = List --> labels, Head = Image --> intensities.  Also, I don't believe there are any disadvantages to convert to `Image`, but I can see many advantages (e.g. checking of the values and dimensions needs to be done once only; after conversion they're guaranteed to be correct)

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thanks for the reassurance and clarification regarding using Image function.

Comment: @Tom I tried to clarify and edited out the "confusing" part—sorry about that.

Comment: Looks really clear now, great :)